# Custom validation message for specific field in gravity form not working

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to add custom validation message for any field, but its show only default error message.

[image: Custom validation message]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a snippet that should fix your issue. I just ran into this myself and didn't understand why it wasn't working. Just drop it into your theme functions.php file.

```
<?php

add_filter( 'gform_field_validation', 'mytheme_fix_custom_validation', 10, 4 );

/**
 * Fixes Gravity Forms Custom validation message.
 *
 * @param array  $result  The result array.
 * @param string $value   The value of the field.
 * @param array  $form    The Gravity Form array.
 * @param object $field   The form field object.
 *
 * @return array  The result array.
 */
function mytheme_fix_custom_validation( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    if ( ! $result['is_valid'] && ! empty( $field->errorMessage ) ) {
        $result['message'] = $field->errorMessage;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Here's a gist in case it ever changes:
https://gist.github.com/solepixel/c8ab2ff61ed55bffa52b5b2a21663c0f

It uses the filter documented here:
https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_validation/